# Can you publish an app (Play Store) that contains an existing database?

Tags: android, sqlite, google-play

I have an app containing multiple buttons, that will be taken out of a database (SQLite).

Do I have to build this database when the app first get started by the user or can I publish the app inclusive the database? And do images on the "internal storage" act the same way?

Comment: Your Question is not very clear..

Comment: See linked duplicate - and you can do the same thing for any images which you decide you need as actually distinct file in the internal storage file system, though normally you don't need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a predefined database delivered within your app. Simply copy it from an app resource (raw folder) to the database location or load a database from the server. I once did a project in which we copied a pre-created sqlite database from the server to the app during startup.